# How to wrap a python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to implement a class that will *wrap* -- not subclass -- the python `dict` object, so that when a change is detected in a backing store I can re-create the delegated dict object. I intend to check for changes in the backing store each time the dict is accessed for a read.

Supposing I was to create an object to act like this; what methods would I need to implement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can subclass the [ABC](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#abcs-abstract-base-classes) (abstract base class) `collections.Mapping` (or `collections.MutableMapping` if you also want to allow code using your instances to alter the simulated/wrapped dictionary, e.g. by indexed assignment, `pop`, etc).

If you do so, then, as the docs I pointed to imply somewhat indirectly, the methods you need to implement are

```
__len__
__iter__
__getitem__
```

(for a `Mapping`) -- you **should** also implement

```
__contains__
```

because by delegating to the dict you're wrapping it can be done much faster than the iterating approach the ABC would have to apply otherwise.

If you need to supply a `MutableMapping` then you also need to implement 2 more methods:

```
__setitem__
__delitem__
```

Comment: Is there any way, in python 3, to forward all those methods "in bulk", without manually copy/pasting nearly identical code for each of them? The normal `__getattr__` doesn't work since special methods are looked up on the class instead of instance, and that lookup skips `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what's already been suggested, you might want to take a look at [UserDict](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html).

For an example of a dict like object, you can read through django's [session implementation](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py), specifically the `SessionBase` class.

Comment: As suggested by the documentation link supplied, UserDict has pretty much been supplanted by dict subclasses (since Python 2.2) and the ABC approach suggested by Alex Martelli above (since Python 2.6).

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on which methods you use. Probably `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__iter__` and `__len__` as most things can be implemented in terms of those. But you'll want to look at some use cases, particularly with `__iter__`. Something like this:

```
for key in wrapped_dictionary:
   do_something(wrapped_dictionary[key])
```

...is going to be slow if you hit the data source on each iteration, not to mention that it might not even work if the data source is changing out from under you. So you'll want to maybe throw some sort of exception there and implement `iteritems` as an alternative, loading all the key-value pairs in one batch before you loop over them.

The [Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) have item listings where you can look for methods and use-cases.